# Having an issue using TextFeild in flutter, Text box not showing up

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a flutter app that requires a user to complete certain tasks in order to stop an alarm clock. It's a more immersive alarm clock app that could help stimulate the brain in order to aid in the process of waking up.

The tasks are simple questions the user has to answer. I'm utilizing TextFeild() to allow the user to input their answer. However, when I go to debug my code is redirected to a file called box.dart this is where the error is stated.

Here is the box.dart file error:

```
throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
          ErrorSummary('Cannot hit test a render box with no size.'),
          describeForError('The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox'),
          ErrorDescription(
            'Although this node is not marked as needing layout, '
            'its size is not set.',
          ),
          ErrorHint(
            'A RenderBox object must have an '
            'explicit size before it can be hit-tested. Make sure '
            'that the RenderBox in question sets its size during layout.',
          ),
        ]);
      }
```

Here is my full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
//import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Time Attack',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Time Attack'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            // ignore: avoid_print
            print("alarm is playing");
            final player = AudioCache();
            //bool isPLaying = false;
            await player.load('musicForapp.mp3');
            AudioPlayer p = AudioPlayer();
            p.audioCache = player;
            await p.play(AssetSource('musicForapp.mp3'));
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          child: const Icon(Icons.punch_clock),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(170),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Text(
                "Click the Icon in the bottem right to simulate alarm",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => const TasksPage(),
                    ),
                  );
                }, //on pressed
                child: const Text(
                  "Tasks page",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
}

class TasksPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TasksPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TasksPage> createState() => _TasksPageState();
}

class _TasksPageState extends State<TasksPage> {
  final _textcontroller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Tasks'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => const SecondTask(),
              ),
            );
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          child: const Text("Next"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "How many states are there in the United States of America?",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _textcontroller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Type your answer here!",
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _textcontroller.clear();
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
}

class SecondTask extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondTask({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecondTask> createState() => _SecondTask();
}

class _SecondTask extends State<SecondTask> {
  final _textcontroller2 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Tasks'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => const Thirdtask(),
              ),
            );
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          child: const Text("Next"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "how many oceans are there?",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _textcontroller2,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Type your answer here!",
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _textcontroller2.clear();
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
}

class Thirdtask extends StatefulWidget {
  const Thirdtask({super.key});

  @override
  State<Thirdtask> createState() => _Thirdtask();
}

class _Thirdtask extends State<Thirdtask> {
  final _textcontroller3 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Tasks'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => const Finaltask(),
              ),
            );
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          child: const Text("Next"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "What is 8 x 7?",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _textcontroller3,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Type your answer here!",
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _textcontroller3.clear();
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
}

class Finaltask extends StatefulWidget {
  const Finaltask({super.key});

  @override
  State<Finaltask> createState() => _Finaltask();
}

class _Finaltask extends State<Finaltask> {
  final _textcontroller4 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Tasks'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => const Congrats(),
              ),
            );
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          child: const Text("Submit"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "Riddle: What goes up but never comes back down?",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _textcontroller4,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Type your answer here!",
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _textcontroller4.clear();
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
}

class Congrats extends StatefulWidget {
  const Congrats({super.key});

  @override
  State<Congrats> createState() => _Congrats();
}

class _Congrats extends State<Congrats> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Good Job!'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => const MyHomePage(),
              ),
            );
            //player.clear('explosion.mp3');  (to stop alarm)
            // ignore: avoid_print
            print("Alarm has stoped");
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          child: const Text("Home"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: const [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Congratulations you completed your tasks, Click the home button to return home and stop the timer!",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 30.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please delete all `MaterialApp` (except the first on the top). Because in Flutter app there must be only one `MaterialApp` throughout the code.

Secondly, juste change your padding 170 to 17 for exemple. 170 is extremely big.

Answer (score 0):

Use single `MaterialApp` on top widget as @Antonin Liehn said. Now for the `TextFormField` border. You need to use `enabledBorder`, also try others border property , Find more about [`OutlineInputBorder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlineInputBorder-class.html).

```dart
decoration: InputDecoration(
  hintText: "Type your answer here!",
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: 22,
    ),
  ),
  errorBorder: ,
  focusedBorder: ,
  disabledBorder: ,
  focusedErrorBorder: ,
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: 22,
    ),
  ),
```

Also wrap text with `Flexible`/`Expanded` widget. You cal follow this widget

```dart
class TasksPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TasksPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TasksPage> createState() => _TasksPageState();
}

class _TasksPageState extends State<TasksPage> {
  final _textcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final border = const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.white,
    width: 22,
  ));
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: const Text('Taskssssssss'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => const SecondTask(),
            ),
          );
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: const Text("Next"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: const Text(
                  "How many states are there in the United States of America?",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _textcontroller,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Type your answer here!",
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    errorBorder: border,
                    focusedBorder: border,
                    disabledBorder: border,
                    focusedErrorBorder: border,
                    border: border,
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _textcontroller.clear();
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
}
```